# Mongo can't connect to remote instance

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb on remote server via vagrant. I can access postgres from my local system but mongo is not available. When I login via ssh and check mongo status it says that mongo running, I can make queries too. When I try to connect from my local system using this command:

```
mongo 192.168.192.168:27017
```

I get an error

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: 192.168.192.168:27017/test
2014-12-27T22:19:19.417+0100 warning: Failed to connect to 192.168.192.168:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-12-27T22:19:19.418+0100 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.192.168:27017 (192.168.192.168), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

looks like mongo not listen to connection from other ips? I commented bind_ip in mongo settings but it doesn't help.

services for 192.168.192.168 via nmap command:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
5432/tcp open  postgresql
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

Looks like mongd listen

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep mongo
mongod    1988     mongodb    6u  IPv4   5407      0t0  TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)
mongod    1988     mongodb    8u  IPv4   5411      0t0  TCP *:28017 (LISTEN)
```

Firewall rules

```
sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Update**
My mongo config

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true
```

Comment: Have you checked for firewall rules and confirmed mongodb is in fact listening on port 27017 on interface `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: If its a vagrant instance you might have to setup a port forward between your VM and the host... Might be that this is already done automatically for your postgress. Check your Vagrantfile.

Comment: @Blizz My vagrantfile is very basic, it has debian-7.4 and config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.192.168", I added forwarded port and it's work but it's only workaround I think

Answer (score 7):

Solution is to change mongo configuration
`bind_ip = 0.0.0.0`

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit?